# Getting the value stored from register in llvm IR

Tags: c++, llvm

I have a simple C program.

```
int
1.main(int argc, char **argv) {
2.  unsigned buffer[4] = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
3.  return buffer[argc];
4. }
```

And the IR code is as below

```
; Function Attrs: norecurse nounwind readnone uwtable
define i32 @main(i32 %argc, i8** nocapture readnone %argv) #0 !dbg !6 {
  %buffer = alloca [4 x i32], align 16
  tail call void @llvm.dbg.value(metadata i32 %argc, i64 0, metadata !14, metadata !21), !dbg !22
  tail call void @llvm.dbg.value(metadata i8** %argv, i64 0, metadata !15, metadata !21), !dbg !23
  %1 = bitcast [4 x i32]* %buffer to i8*, !dbg !24
  call void @llvm.lifetime.start(i64 16, i8* %1) #3, !dbg !24
  tail call void @llvm.dbg.declare(metadata [4 x i32]* %buffer, metadata !16, metadata !21), !dbg !25
  call void @llvm.memset.p0i8.i64(i8* %1, i8 0, i64 16, i32 16, i1 false), !dbg !26
  %2 = sext i32 %argc to i64, !dbg !28
  %3 = getelementptr inbounds [4 x i32], [4 x i32]* %buffer, i64 0, i64 %2, !dbg !28
  %4 = load i32, i32* %3, align 4, !dbg !28, !tbaa !29
  call void @llvm.lifetime.end(i64 16, i8* %1) #3, !dbg !33
  ret i32 %4, !dbg !34
}
```

I want to compare whether the accessing index at line 3 is a valid index. For this comparison I need to extract the value stored for the argc. Below is piece of code I have written to obain the vvalue of argc

```
auto gep = llvm::dyn_cast<llvm::GetElementPtrInst>(inst);
auto operand2 = gep->getOperand(2);
outs() << "operand 2 "<<*operand2<<"\n";
auto newOperand =operand2.getOperand(0);
outs()<<"New operand "<<*newOperand<<"\n";
```

Output :-

operand 2   %2 = sext i32 %argc to i64, !dbg !28

New operand i32 %argc

How can I get the value of %argc?

Answer (score 0):

The return value of `getOperand` function is `Value*` object of the `argc` variable (variable `newOperand` in your code). You can pass that value to any new instruction that you might want to inject (for example `CreateICmpEQ`) in the IR to compare value of `argc` with some constant value.